# Store primitive values in an EnumMap

Tags: java, enums, enum-map

Why can't I create an `EnumMap` like this:

```
EnumMap<FunkyTrolls, int> amountMap;
```

I want to count and save the number of trolls of each type. What is a good way of doing this?

Comment: by using the EnumMap you are already using, but with Integers?

Comment: You may be better off making each enum produce a small `int`, and then use an array instead of a map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `Integer`. Generics only work on objects, not on primitive types, but Java now has auto-boxing and -unboxing.

This should work:

```
Map<FunkyTrolls, Integer> amountMap = new EnumMap<FunkyTrolls, Integer>();
amountMap.put(FunkyTrolls.VERY_FUNKY_TROLL, 100);
```

Comment: So Integer is a wrapper class for the primitive int? What is auto-boxing?

Comment: `Integer` is the object variant of `int`. Auto-boxing is "converting" the int to an Integer object instance by the compiler (so you seem to store an `int`, but it is converted to `Integer`). Note that `null` can probably be stored in the `Map`, but an `int` can obviously not be null (as isn't an object reference at all, just a value). I'll let you guess auto-unboxing :)

Comment: Thanks. Although I just noticed I want to do ++ for the amounts (while looping over the funky trolls). Probably a Map is not so good for this after all...

Comment: Depends, if your code should really run super-fast, then you might get into trouble. Otherwise you just loop over the keys, get the value, increment it and put it back in.

Comment: Loop over the keys? Can I just use amountMap.put(VERY_FUNKY_TROLL,(amountMap.get(VERY_FUNKY_TROLL)+1))? If assure that there is already an entry for this funky troll.

Comment: Yes you can. But I would spread it over multiple lines of course. Just add all trolls at the start, with a count of zero, and you can be 100% sure there is an entry :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30286/discussion-between-owlstead-and-moberg)

Comment: @Moberg There is no problem in such approach, but you will be in trouble in multi-threaded situation. (thread 1 and 2 both get the old value, increment it and set with oldValue+1, while the correct result should be oldValue+2).  Proper synchronization control is needed if this piece of code is going to be run in multiple thread